# Camel File Split and Aggregate

Tags: apache-camel

I am working on processing a large file that has CSV format and I have used split to break the CSV. Here is the sample file format:

```
  **Item1,Item2,Item3,Item4
  Item1,Item5,Item7,Item2**
```

Here is my route information:

```
 <route>
  <from uri="file://Data/groupedDocs?preMove=staging&amp;delete=false" />
   <split streaming="true" parallelProcessing="true">
     <tokenize token="\n" group="1" />
     <to uri="bean:groupProcessor" />
   </split>
  <log message="File Sent!!!"/>
 </route>
```

In the above code, my `groupProcessor` is processing the individual line from the CSV file.

The issue is, how would I know if all the records have been processed? There could be 10 or 100 records. I saw the aggregator pattern but the problem is I do not want to aggregate i.e. I am not reading all the records and dumping them in a file. I am creating a new file for each line from the CSV file. It may also be possible that some of the lines in CSV file may generate an error so for the errored out entries, I am not creating any new file. E.g. in CSV file I have 10 lines and out of them 2 throw some exception so I'll have to log these 2 as exceptions and generate 8 files for rest of the entries. At the end, I also need to keep the count of number of new files generated and errored out. Can anyone please help in here?

Comment: See this answer of mine Camel aggregation strategy http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26346772/camel-aggregation-strategy/26348903#26348903

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set some flag in header if there was an exception, and you can count that flags in [aggregationStrategy](http://camel.apache.org/splitter.html) (section `Split aggregate request/reply sample`). Attribute strategyRef in xml